# Is there a way to tell a chromecast receiver app on initialization which splash image to ues?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I have a CAF receiver that I want to use with multiple sender apps. Depending on the sender app, I'd like to display a different splash image. I can't find any way to tell my receiver app during initialization, which splash image to use.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: I've tried updating the splash screen during an intercepted onLoad message. That works, but at that point, the default splash screen has already been displayed and then it changes, which is not good.

I'm pretty sure I can also send a message as soon as a connection is made, but I expect to find the same problem as with onLoad. The problem being that there's some time between the the app loading and when I can actually change the splash screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two different app IDs that go to the same url, but with some URL options on it https://yourReceiver.com/index.html?sender=,then parse the URL options in the receiver. The splash screen image can be changed at run time using JS: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/customize_ui#styling-the-player

Comment: Hmm. That's not a bad idea. It's not ideal. I'd love to not have multiple apps. But since the only thing that would need to be passed in the url is the splash image, this could be the best solution. Everything else I can update as you said once a session is started.